# Angular - Reactive Form: How to correctly get values of dynamical and reusable sub-forms

Tags: angular, typescript, forms, angular-reactive-forms

I am working on a form as below

[image]

[image]

My code

nested-form.component.ts

```
public nestedForm: FormGroup;
constructor(
    private formBuilder: FormBuilder) {
    this.calibrationForm = this.buildFormGroup(formBuilder);

  }

buildFormGroup(formBuilder: FormBuilder): FormGroup {
    return  new FormGroup({
      motor: new FormControl('', Validators.required),
      properties: new FormControl(""),
    });
  }

save() {
    console.log(this.nestedForm.value);
}
```

nested-form.component.html

```
<form [formGroup]="nestedForm" >

    <mat-select class="field-select" [(ngModel)]="_selectedMotor"
                    (selectionChange)="selectMotor($event.value)" formControlName="motor">
                    <mat-option class="select-option" *ngFor="let item of motors" [value]="item">
                        item</b>
                    </mat-option>
                </mat-select>

    <app-properties formControlName="properties" [type] = "_selectedMotor"></app-properties>
   ...
</form>
```

properties.component.ts

```
@Component({
  ...
  providers: [
    {
      provide: NG_VALUE_ACCESSOR,
      useExisting: forwardRef(() => PropertiesComponent),
      multi: true
    },
    {
      provide: NG_VALIDATORS,
      useExisting: forwardRef(() => PropertiesComponent),
      multi: true
    }
  ]
})

export class PropertiesComponent implements OnInit, ControlValueAccessor {
    @Input() type: string = null;
    public propertiesForm: FormGroup;
    ngOnInit(): void {
        this.propertiesForm = this.buildFormGroup(this.formBuilder);
    }

    ngOnChanges(changes): void {
        this.propertiesForm = this.buildFormGroup(this.formBuilder);
    }

    buildFormGroup(formBuilder: FormBuilder): FormGroup {
        switch (this.type) {
          case "OLD":
           
            return new FormGroup(
              {
                tilt: new FormControl(0, [Validators.required]),
                fine_tilt: new FormControl(0, [Validators.required]),
                rotate: new FormControl(0, [Validators.required]),
                fine_rotate: new FormControl(0, [Validators.required])
              });

          case "VINTEN":
           
            return new FormGroup(
              {
                vinten_tilt: new FormControl(0, [Validators.required]),
                vinten_rotate: new FormControl(0, [Validators.required])

              });
        }
     }

  public onTouched: () => void = () => { };
  writeValue(val: any): void {
    val && this.propertiesForm.setValue(val, { emitEvent: false });
  }
  registerOnChange(fn: any): void {
    this.propertiesForm.valueChanges.subscribe(fn);
  }
  registerOnTouched(fn: any): void {
    this.onTouched = fn;
  }
  setDisabledState?(isDisabled: boolean): void {
    isDisabled ? this.propertiesForm.disable() : this.propertiesForm.enable();
  }

  validate(c: AbstractControl): ValidationErrors | null {
    return this.propertiesForm.valid ? null : { invalidForm: { valid: false, message: "propertiesForm fields are invalid" } };
  }
  ...
}
```

properties.component.html

```
<form *ngIf="type" class="col" [formGroup]="propertiesForm" [ngSwitch]="type">
    <div *ngSwitchCase="OLD">
        <input type="number" class="field-input" id="rotate" formControlName="rotate" />
        <input type="number" class="field-input" id="fine_rotate" formControlName="fine_rotate" />
        <input type="number" class="field-input" id="tilt" formControlName="tilt" />
        <input type="number" class="field-input" id="fine_tilt" formControlName="fine_tilt" />
    </div>

    <div *ngSwitchCase="VINTEN">
        <input type="number" class="field-input" id="rotate" formControlName="vinten_rotate" />
        <input type="number" class="field-input" id="tilt" formControlName="vinten_tilt" />
    </div>
</form>
```

Result:

Let's say OLD is a default, when the form is loaded.

I entered all fields and click Save button for OLD, the form values is collected correctly as expected.

However, when I switched from OLD to VINTEN, the form UI is updated but valid/invalid state of Save button is not working any more, and after clicking Save button, the form values are still the OLD properties values, not VINTEN properties values.

Did I miss something or make something wrong? Any suggestion is appreciated.

Comment: I don't see in your Properties component implementation of  ControlValueAccessor interface. Once you have it you can emit changes to the parent control

Comment: Yes, I implemented all required ones for ControlValueAccessor. I didn't include them to the sample code, to keep the code short, just the main code.

Comment: FYI: To implement ControlValueAccessor, I followed this article: https://medium.com/angular-in-depth/angular-nested-reactive-forms-using-cvas-b394ba2e5d0d

Comment: Could you replicate the problem into a StackBlitz app or something like that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To notify parent control about internal changes you have to listen `propertiesForm.valueChanges()`.

And call `fn` that you were given by  `registerOnChange(fn: any): void`

```
onModelChange = () => {}


 ngOnInit(): void {
    this.propertiesForm = this.buildFormGroup(this.formBuilder);
    this.propertiesForm.valueChanges().subscribe(value => this.onModelChange(value))
}

registerOnChange(fn: any): void {
  this.onModelChange = fn;
}
```

[Angular forms](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=CD_t3m2WMM8&list=LL&index=18&t=1720s)

Comment: I implemented one of the ControlValueAccessor: registerOnChange(fn: any): void {
    this.propertiesForm.valueChanges.subscribe(fn);
  } . Is it the same logic?

Comment: Two ways are valid. But if you want to call `onModelChange` in other places you need to store reference

Comment: Thanks, I got the solution. I accept your answer, for my specific issue, refer to my answer.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks Yuriry,

Though his answer didn't resolve my issue directly and fully, it's a main lead for me to the final solution of my issue. Just leave here for any reference:

```
export class PropertiesComponent implements OnInit, ControlValueAccessor {
    @Input() type: string = null;
    subscriptions: Subscription[] = [];

    ...

    ngOnChanges(changes): void {
       this.subscriptions.forEach(s => s.unsubscribe());
       this.propertiesForm = this.buildFormGroup(this.formBuilder);
       this.subscriptions.push(
           this.propertiesForm.valueChanges.subscribe(value => {
             this.onChange(value);
             this.onTouched();
         })
       );
    }
    
    ...
   onChange: any = () => {};
   registerOnChange(fn: any): void {
     this.onChange = fn;
   }
}
```